# hover не работает с font-awesome icon

Tags: html, css, css3, fontawesome

Мне нужно показать стрелку на `hover` внутри ссылки, но я не могу этого сделать.
Как я могу это исправить?
Кроме того, я попытался получить значок по классам `.fas`, `.fa-arrow-right` и  попытался получить тег `path`, но результат тот же.

```css
.header-text-links a {
  display: block;
  width: 278px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #fab608;
  color: #fab608;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Futura Demi";
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-text-links a .svg-inline--fa {
  display: none;
}

.header-text-links a:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #fab608;
  text-decoration: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.header-text-links a:hover .header-text-links a .svg-inline--fa {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js"></script>
<div class="header-text-links">
  <a class="header-text-links__works" href="#">Some text<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [hover not working with font-awesome icon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49317006/7394871) от участника  [@Yaroslav Saenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9131557/yaroslav-saenko).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/49317006/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете неправильный селектор ... пробуйте - `.header-text-links a: hover .svg-inline -- fa`

Для лучшего понимания удалите: `:hover`  всего на один раз, чтобы он выглядел так:

`.header-text-links a .header-text-links a .svg-inline--fa`

Что означает,-  он будет нацелен на `.svg-inline-fa` внутри `.header-text-links a`  снова внутри `.header-text-links a`

```css
.header-text-links a {
  display: block;
  width: 278px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #fab608;
  color: #fab608;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Futura Demi";
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-text-links a .svg-inline--fa {
  display: none;
}

.header-text-links a:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #fab608;
  text-decoration: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.header-text-links a:hover .svg-inline--fa {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js"></script>
<div class="header-text-links">
  <a class="header-text-links__works" href="#">Some text<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [hover not working with font-awesome icon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49317041/7394871) от участника  [@Bhuwan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6700627/bhuwan).</sub>